# Como hacer que un boton no se pueda presionar por cierto periodo de tiempo? Javascript

Tags: javascript, botón, animación

Tengo un botón que ejecuta una animación, el problema radica en que puedo presionar el botón rápidamente y la animación se reiniciaba, entonces busco una manera de "Dormir" el botón para evitar que se reinicie la animación.

Me pregunto si habrá algún método para eso, solo encuentro el método "sleep()" pero solo me sirve para dormir una función, así que creo que ninguna me da solución.

Por si sirve de algo, el tipo de botón que usé es el de HTML .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function bloquear(duracionBloqueo, boton){

  boton.disabled = true;
  
  // habilitarlo después la duración de bloqueo especificada
  setTimeout(() => boton.disabled = false, duracionBloqueo);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="bloquear(1000, this)">boton</button>
```

Comment: Gracias Bro, si funcionó, solo tengo una pequeña duda, el setTimeout no detiene la ejecucion de otros procesos,osea solamente se ejecuta dentro de esa funcion y no afecta nada mas no?

Comment: Así es, es asíncrono.

Answer (score 0):

se puede hacer con la propiedad `disabled` y el evento `animationend`

El HTML y estilos:

```
<style>
    /* The animation code */
    @keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
    }

/* The element to apply the animation to */
    .animado {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 4s;
    }

    .div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }

</style>

<div id="animacion" class="div"></div>

<button id="boton">Iniciar</button>
<script src="archivojs.js"></script>
```

El archivo js:

```
boton = document.getElementById('boton');
elementoAnimado = document.getElementById('animacion');

function iniciarAnimacion() {
    elementoAnimado.classList.add('animado');
}

boton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.disabled = true;
    iniciarAnimacion();
});

elementoAnimado.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
    boton.disabled = false;
    elementoAnimado.classList.remove('animado');
});
```

tener en cuenta compatibilidad con navegadores antiguos:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp